# Shows error "Cannot POST" when I try to submit the HTML form

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, backend

I have seen other questions with the same error, but none of the answers seem to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8080/del" method="post">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Click on the submit button, and the input will be sent to a page on the server called "http://127.0.0.1:8080/del".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
var express=require('express');
var body_parser=require('body-parser');
var request = require('request').defaults({json:true});
var app=express();
var del=require('./del'); 
app.post('./del',del.test);
var server = app.listen(8080,function(){
    var host="127.0.0.1";
    var port="8080";
    console.log("App is listening at http://%s:%s\n",host,port);
});
```

**del.js**

```
module.exports={
    test: function(){
        console.log("Hello world.");
    }
};
```

Each time, when I submit the form, it shows

> Cannot POST /del

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your **server.js** change this line:

```
app.post('./del',del.test);
```

to this:

```
app.post('/del',del.test);
```

then you have correct router.

And your **del.js** change to this:

```
module.exports={
    test: function(req, res){
        console.log("Hello world.");
        res.status(200).end();
    }
};
```

because router function should return response.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. If my answer is correct, please accept it.

Comment: Not enough reputation to vote up your answer :'( 
Sorry!

Comment: Yes I understand, but you are OP, therefore you also have possibility to accept answer "As the author of the question, you'll see an outline of a checkmark on the left side of each answer. It'll be right below the up and down vote arrows. Click the checkmark next to the post that best answers your question to accept that answer as the best one."