# I'm having a cannot POST when attempting to submit a form with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an issue with my Javascript and HTML where when I submit my form, I get a Cannot POST error. I already looked at [Shows error "Cannot POST" when I try to submit the HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574522/shows-error-cannot-post-when-i-try-to-submit-the-html-form), but that seems to be server-based. I'm sorry, but I'm doing this for a class, so I'm in a bit of a time crunch right now.

My login JS code:

```
function login(){
    var pw = document.forms['login']['passcode'].value;
    var email = document.forms['login']["email"].value;
    var login = userLogin().get();
    if(email == "adrian@tissue.com" && pw == "welcome1"){
        window.location = "issues.html";
    }
    else if(email == "admin@tissue.com" && pw == "admin123"){
        window.location = "subscription-dashboard.html"
    }
    else if(email == login[0] && pw == login[1]){
        window.location = "issues.html";
    }
    else{
        alert("That password/email is incorrect");
        return false;
    };
}
```

My module for get is:

```
(function userLogin(){
return {
    store: function(password, email){
        sessionStorage.setItem(pass, password);
        sessionStorage.setItem(user, email);
        return false;
    },
    get: function(){
        var mail = sessionStorage.getItem(user);
        var pwkey = sessionStorage.getItem(pass);
        var loginfo = [mail, pwkey];
        return loginfo;
    }
}
});
```

And my HTML code is:

```
<form action="#" name="login" method="post" onsubmit="return login()">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        <input type="password" name="passcode" placeholder = "Password" required>
        <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

Here's my fiddle for ease. I'm using Brackets and this class is Client side JS.
https://jsfiddle.net/MiguelPi/nmp6oxat/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to access to an anonymous function, rewrite `userFunction` like this (without external parentheses):

```
function userLogin(){
  return {
    store: function(password, email){
      sessionStorage.setItem(pass, password);
      sessionStorage.setItem(user, email);
      return false;
    },
    get: function(){
      var mail = sessionStorage.getItem(user);
      var pwkey = sessionStorage.getItem(pass);
      var loginfo = [mail, pwkey];
      return loginfo;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding, but that doesn't seem to have been it. It still is saying Cannot POST /index.html for reason.

Comment: Could you add the rest of your code so we can see where's the problem? It appears that you're using node.js.

Comment: It's like you haven't set an appropiate route to handle the request in your backend.

Comment: I added a fiddle, and I have quite a bit of code but I'm pretty sure this is where the issue lies? I only call modules.js and login.js on my index page.

Comment: Since it is an only client side web page you cannot get "Cannot POST" (unless you actually have a page whose content is this, but I don't think so) error anywhere, it's usually seen on frameworks that handle requests made. You must be getting 404, in case your page wasn't found.

Comment: Then perhaps I'm doing something completely wrong, as I can prove that's the error I'm getting. Maybe it's something with the live brackets preview? Ah, okay, it was something with brackets. We should move this to a chat as I have a different issue now. It's not properly executing the JS.